# WSDL not updating after change the service implementation

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I have created a `SOAP` based `webservice` using `Apache-CXF3.xxx` version in eclipse and deploy this on `tomact6` server. The `webservice` deployed on tomcat working fine from `SOAP UI` client.

But the problem is when I'm changing Implementation and redeploy,  the `WSDL` is not updating, ex. if I have two implementation methods and I exclude one of them `@WebMethod(exclude = true)` but still `WSDL` showing excluded method.

Looks like `WSDL` is not refreshing. Any Idea how can resolve it or I need to create `WSDL` every time after making change in implementation?

Comment: do you other properties in `@WebMethod()` annotation for this method (`name` or `action`)?

Comment: Did you already try a clean-build cycle, e.g. `mvn clean install`?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou : I have no other properties with Webmethod annotation

Comment: This is not maven project just dynamic web project without maven nature so I clean and redploy it.

Comment: How are you inspecting the wsdl? Could this be a client caching issue?

Comment: from SOAP UI, also I can see from eclipse its still same.